# Parameter type may not live long enough

Tags: rust

I have a simple program where I am trying to implement a polymorphic account type:

```
enum AccountType {
    INVALID,
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
}

trait Account {
    fn get_name(&self) -> String;
    fn get_type(&self) -> AccountType;
}

struct Accounts {
    accounts: Vec<Box<Account>>,
}

impl Accounts {
    fn new() -> Accounts {
        let accs: Vec<Box<Account>> = Vec::new();
        Accounts { accounts: accs }
    }

    fn add_account<A: Account>(&self, account: A) {
        self.accounts.push(Box::new(account));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let accounts = Accounts::new();
}
```

([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2c29133bb6a525d955d35bff96a5feea&version=stable))

When I compile it, I see the following error:

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `A` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:23:28
   |
22 |     fn add_account<A: Account>(&self, account: A) {
   |                    -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `A: 'static`...
23 |         self.accounts.push(Box::new(account));
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `A` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:23:28
   |
23 |         self.accounts.push(Box::new(account));
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have tried adding lifetimes to the type but could not find the right way to do it. Please let me know if this is not the right way to do polymorphism in Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler's suggestion actually works. If you write `add_account` as follows:

```
fn add_account<A: Account + 'static>(&mut self, account: A) {
    self.accounts.push(Box::new(account));
}
```

your code compiles. (Incidentally, you need `&mut self`, not `&self` here)

Comment: It's probably worth explaining why the error occurs and why the modified code fixes it.

Comment: Thanks. Doest the lifetime have to be `static` in this case?

Comment: @russoue Yes. The point of this bound is that the trait object cannot be allowed to outlive anything it references. The `'static` bound means that the object cannot have any non-static references.

Comment: @fjh Thanks. If I understood it correctly, having the `static` lifetime means an object lives as long as the program runs. In that case, how do I add an `Account` to the vector which has longer lifetime than an instance of `Accounts` but shorter than `static`? Is it not possible?

Comment: @russoue I'm actually not sure. It might be possible by adding a lifetime parameter to `Accounts`. I'm a bit out of my depth here and I'm not near a computer so I can't experiment right now. I'll play around with it later and let you know if I find out.

Comment: `'static` does not mean "an object lives as long as the program". In trait bounds `'static` (or any other lifetime bound) means that the type must not contain references with lifetimes shorter than the specified one. Note that *absence* of references qualifies too - therefore, every type which does not contain references inside it (or, in other words, which does not have any type parameters) satisfies any lifetime bound.

Comment: Oh, I made a silly mistake, sorry. Of course, "type parameters" should be read as "lifetime parameters".

Answer (score 11):

I'll try to give a more thorough answer: the issue has to do with the definition of the `accounts` member of `Accounts`.  `Vec<Box<Account>>` in this context is equivalent to `Vec<Box<Account + 'static>>`, i.e. the box can't contain any references to data on the stack.  On the other hand, the declaration of `add_account` doesn't restrict the lifetime of the type: it's equivalent to `fn add_account<'a, A: Account + 'a>(&self, account: A) {`.

The solution is to make sure the type A lives long enough.  The simplest approach is to just add the `A: 'static` bound suggested in the error message (`fn add_account<A: Account + 'static>(&self, account: A) {`).

If you don't want to copy the Account data, you can do something more complicated, like this:

```
struct Accounts<'a> {
    accounts: Vec<&'a Account + 'a>
}

impl<'a> Accounts<'a> {
    fn new() -> Accounts<'a> {
        Accounts { accounts: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn add_account<A: Account + 'a>(&mut self, account: &'a A) {
        self.accounts.push(Box::new(account));
    }
}
```

At this point, though, you have a data structure which is probably more general than you actually need.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by `Vec<Box<Account>> in this context is equivalent to Vec<Box<Account + 'static>>` ?  I mean, what in the code above indicates that it is equivalent to `Vec<Box<Account + 'static>>` ?

Comment: Every trait object has an associated lifetime; if you don't specify a lifetime, the compiler infers it using some simple rules.  https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-02-advanced-lifetimes.html#trait-object-lifetimes has a general description; https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/8ee535b4fcc8bb22c121ad19a36414f1259397c0/text/0599-default-object-bound.md has the rationale.

Comment: What happened when I add `'static`?