# Is it possible to have a struct definition with a generic where a type is both a type of trait and with a lifetime?

Tags: rust

Edit: Question as the title modified by Shepmaster. Added more details to the situation.

I'm wanting to have access to an object following a trait in different threads, stored overall in a struct. As I'm porting my code from another language to try to learn rust, I'm still a bit of a newbie to the language.

Originally I thought to have a struct similar to the following, which compiled fine:

```
struct MyStruct<T : MyTrait> {
    my_object : Arc<Mutex<T>>
}
```

However, ultimately I need to store a reference to to it as it will be stored in multiple threads. I understand I need to use lifetimes as well to get this to work, so I ended up with the following:

```
struct MyStruct<'a, T : MyTrait> {
    my_object : &' Arc<Mutex<T>>
}
```

The error I get is:

> error[E0309]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
>
> -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'a`...
>
> ...so that the reference type `&'a std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<T>>` does not outlive the data it points at
>
> my_object : &' Arc< Mutex < T > >

The error implies that I have to specify the lifetime to my generic, however, I already have a trait for my type. So Ultimately, how can I specify that a generic type both follow a trait and have a lifetime?

Comment: The code you have posted is not syntactically valid Rust code.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Why is the bound `T: 'a` required in order to store a reference `&'a T`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41794800/155423); [The compiler suggests I add a 'static lifetime because the parameter type may not live long enough, but I don't think that's what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40053550/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Parameter type may not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32625583/155423); [Parameter type may not live long enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29740488/155423); [Why “explicit lifetime bound required” for Box<T> in struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25959075/155423); and basically any other question that mentions your error message.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not syntactically valid, otherwise I wouldn't have posted the error message when trying to compile. Your edited question title is exactly what I was asking for; however, I've put in additional details.

Comment: *'-- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound T: 'a...'*

Comment: @hellow yes, the question is how to do that and keep the trait as well.

Comment: Ah, I see! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740488/parameter-type-may-not-live-long-enough Should give you the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ultimately, how can I specify that a generic type both follow a trait and have a lifetime?

The same way you'd specify multiple traits: add them with `+`. I.e. `T : MyTrait + 'a`